# Galaxy s iii AsyncTask not executed correctly

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am using asynctask for bluetooth socket comminication. It works fine on galaxy s ii(android 2.3.3), but sometimes not work on galaxy s iii(android 4.0.4).

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, long[], Void> {
     long[] d = new long[40];

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.e("BTtest", "MyTask preexecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        int count = 0;
        Log.e("BTtest", "Mytask background start " );
            *******creting socket and streams*******
                    *********logic*******
                    publishProgress(d);
            }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        **logic**           
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(long[]... data) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(data);
                    *******logic***
        }

}
```

from onCreate button function:

```
mt = new MyTask();
mt.execute( );
```

Sometimes on galaxy s iii onPreExecute method is called and doInBackground method not started. 
But other times background method called. It looks like random.

Any ideas?

wildhemp suggested what asynctasks are executed in only one thread. I wrote testing application this 3 asynctasks in one activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 MyTask mt1, mt2, mt3;
  TextView tvInfo;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
  }

  public void onclick(View v) {
        mt1 = new MyTask();
        mt1.execute("file_path_1", "file_path_2", "file_path_3", "file_path_4");
        mt2 = new MyTask();
        mt2.execute("file_path_1", "file_path_2", "file_path_3", "file_path_4");
        mt3 = new MyTask();
        mt3.execute("file_path_1", "file_path_2", "file_path_3", "file_path_4");
  }

  class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      tvInfo.append("Begin \n");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
      try {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (String url : urls) {
          downloadFile(url);
          publishProgress(++cnt);
        }

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
      tvInfo.append("Downloaded " + values[0] + " files \n");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      tvInfo.append("End\n");
    }


    private void downloadFile(String url) throws InterruptedException {
      int i=0;
      while (i<100000000){
          i+=1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it works fine on sgs2, sgs3 and emulator. application loads cpu on 75% (3 threads on 4 cores) on sgs3. sgs2 is loaded on 100%(3 threads on 2 cores). 
It is mean what every asynctask executed in separeted thread.

Problem solved. Thanks.
I have changed project target build version. 
Executing code now:

```
                    mt = new MyTask();

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
                        mt.executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR); //work on sgs3 android 4.0.4
                    }
                    else {
                        mt.execute(); // work on sgs2 android 2.3
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might happen because the doInBackground on 4.0.4 is using 1 thread by default to run all async tasks, so if another doInBackground is still working it will block the execution, and I think in this case the onPreExecute will be called, because it is running on the main thread. In 2.3.3 asynctask uses more threads (AFAIK a new one for every task).

UPDATE:
Here's what the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) says about it:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Comment: It is possible, cuse another asynctask is used in previus activity. How we can execute asynctask in separate thread on ice cream sandwidch?

Comment: asynctasks are executed in separetes threads according to test application.

Comment: Updated my answer. Starting with honeycomb it's executed in one thread, but you can configure it to be parallel.

Comment: So if this was the right answer would you consider accepting it?

Comment: I have add the comment to the qustion

Comment: What I meant, you can mark my answer as accepted, so that everybody who has the same problem can see what is the cause of it.